# which Apache POI jars to add to classpath?

Tags: java, excel, apache, jar

I downloaded apache poi 3.15 but i don't know which jars to include in my classpath(jre/lib/ext) as i have found jars in the following directories:
**poi-3.5**
**lib**
**ooxml-lib**
I use the text editor MaxCode on my mac and compile my java files from shell commands.
Can anyone give me the list of jars to copy to classpath?

Comment: Here is a tutorial that list the files to be added: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_environment.htm. 
It's for a different version but seems to be 
poi-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
ooxml-lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ooxml-lib\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar

Comment: I think, that link will help solve my problem.

Comment: I have not seen for mac configuration but i will try that for linux.

Comment: not working for poi 4.1.0